# Reveal.js and presenter view

Tags: reveal.js

I’m in the progress of evaluation reveal.js for my future presentations. Currently I do not have a beamer at hand to test the following. I'm running the presentations locally on Mac OS X 10.2.2.

Hitting S opens a new browser tab consisting of the current slide, the upcoming slide, speaker notes, and timing.

Does the audience still only see the current slide?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say, it will be 2 different browser windows. The idea would be not to mirror your screen, but rather have different content on the projector and your screen. Then you put the window with the slide on the projector (possibly full screen), and the window with the speaker view on your local screen, just like i.e. keynote would do it. The speaker notes feature is described in https://revealjs.com/speaker-view/

Note that in order to use this feature, you need to be serving your slides from a node.js server (instead of just opening index.html as a file in your browser), as described in https://revealjs.com/installation/#full-setup

Comment: Thanks! Sounds decent!

Comment: I cannot understand. How can I have different content on the projector and the screen????

Comment: Updated the answer to include the need to run a server, plus links to relevant documentation.

Comment: @lutzh Old answer, I know, but are you saying the speaker notes _only_ works from a node server? Or just using node as an example of a local server?

Comment: @havlock I haven't used it in a while (and am not planning to, looking into https://marp.app now..) but my understanding is you have to "npm install" the reveal.js app and run it with node, and that will act as a server. I updated the links to the docs.